# Div outline being covered even with z-index set

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I'm trying to create a sudoku grid, consisting of 9 boxes in a 3x3 grid, each containing 9 cells in a 3x3 grid. However the outline of the boxes are being covered by the outline of the cells of other boxes, even though I've set the z-index of the box class to be higher than the cell class.

I'm still fairly new at webdev, and I'm really stuck on how to fix this!

Thank you!!

edit: I was trying to avoid using borders, because I want to be able to toggle the thick box lines on and off, and with border that was causing things to get resized.

I tried setting the position attribute of each class to something other than static, but that didn't seem to do anything.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    const grid = document.getElementById("puzzle-grid");

    const box = document.createElement("div");

    //generate a box to hold 9 cells
    box.classList.add("box");

    //generate cells inside each box
    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        const cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.classList.add("cell");

        box.appendChild(cell);
    }
    grid.appendChild(box);
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 6px solid black;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    z-index: 1000;
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200, 50);
}

.box {
    outline: 2px solid black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.cell {
    outline: solid 1px #999;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" id="puzzle-grid"></div>
```

Comment: What about using border instead of outline?

Comment: I added an edit about why I'd want to avoid using outline

Answer (score 1):

Use `border` with the `.box` element and you don't need any `z-index` configuration

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    const grid = document.getElementById("puzzle-grid");

    const box = document.createElement("div");

    //generate a box to hold 9 cells
    box.classList.add("box");

    //generate cells inside each box
    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        const cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.classList.add("cell");

        box.appendChild(cell);
    }
    grid.appendChild(box);
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
    width: 300px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 6px solid black;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200, 50);
}
.box {
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cell {
    outline: solid 1px #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" id="puzzle-grid"></div>
```

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned this, but I was trying to avoid borders because I want to be able to toggle the box borders on and off, and that was causing the boxes to resize themselves.

Comment: @SarlCagan93 don't toggle the whole border, toggle only the color from transparent to black and you won't face any resize issue

Comment: but then I have the issue that the border of the child cells doesn't go all the way up to the adjacent cells, because it stops at the transparent border. i.e I want to toggle away the black lines, but still be left with a smaller grey border for the boxes